# Convert two or more numbers from a list so they can be subtracted with one another in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I can't seem to get the following thing right.
As the title states I have a list that i want to move numbers out of and subtract with other numbers from the list.
I have tried many methods from this site but they all seem to give the error

> "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4.61'"

(which is one of the nummers from the list). My code is as follows:

```
with open("kurser.txt") as kurser:
    kurslista_ericsson = []
    radnr = 0
    for rad in kurser:
        if radnr < 67:
            info = rad.strip().split("\t")  
            kurs = info[1]  
            kurslista_ericsson.append(kurs)  
            radnr = radnr + 1
a = int(kurslista_ericsson[36])
b = int(kurslista_ericsson[66])
kursutveckling = b - a
print(kursutveckling)
```

Thank you in advance and sorry if i were unclear with anything, its my first time posting here.

Comment: that's because your input data contains floats... if you want to round, first parse as `float` then truncate with `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`4.61` is a float not an integer.

So you should instead try:

```
a = float(kurslista_ericsson[36])
b = float(kurslista_ericsson[66])
```

If they are stored as numbers within a list (not as strings), remove `float()` outright.

Comment: @Jurkka If it works, it's deemed good manner to _accept_ the answer (click the check mark on the left of the answer)